# How to add the image before the on click event ends?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am a beginner in this android studio and I am trying to insert an image for 1 second to a constraint layout by clicking on it and then deleting all the views that have that constraint layout, I attach the code I have to facilitate reading.

```
constraintLayoutNosotros.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ImageView img = new ImageView(activity)

        img.setId(View.generateViewId());
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.palito2);
        constraintLayout.addView(img);

    }
}
);
```

I want to clarify that the image adds it correctly only that I want it to add it for a period of time and then remove it, but when entering those inner classes I lose control over that.
I was investigating if there is any Listener at the end of the onclick event or something like this and I didn't find anything, I already tried `addOnLayoutChangeListener`, `setOnHierarchyChangeListener` and `setOnTouchListener` and in all of them it always adds the image out of my reach.
The last thing that comes to mind is with some animation but I'm not sure it's the correct way.
sorry for my english, I'm from uruguay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Handler with an amount of seconds you want to stay before removing the view from the layout

Here I am using 3 seconds.

```
constraintLayoutNosotros.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ImageView img = new ImageView(activity)

        img.setId(View.generateViewId());
        img.setImageResource(R.mipmap.palito2);
        constraintLayout.addView(img);


        new Handler(getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                constraintLayout.removeView(image)
            }
        }, 3000); // 3 seconds
        
    }
});
```